# R Checking if data table values are same level

Tags: r, r-factor

Suppose I have a data table, g, that looks like this:

```
g <- read.table(file = textConnection('ID Answers Questions
AA 1111111 222222222
AA 2222222 333333333
BB 3333333 444444444
BB 4444444 555555555
BB 5555555 666666666
CC 6666666 777777777'), header = TRUE)

nlevels(g$ID)
# 3
```

For every different ID, I want to create a random hexcolor and assign it to a variable, in this case there are three, given by this for loop:

```
for(j in 1:nlevels(g$ID)) {
  rcolor <- paste(sample(0:255,size=3,replace=TRUE),collapse=" ")
  assign(paste0("IDcolor", j), rcolor)
}

IDcolor1
# [1] "50 25 197"      # <--corresponds to AA
IDcolor2
# [1] "131 255 58"     # <--corresponds to BB
IDcolor3
# [1] "242 100 72"     # <--corresponds to CC
```

So there would be three variables for each of the three levels, AA, BB, and CC.

I want to output each of rows with the correct hex color, however I don't know how to check which value in g[,1] corresponds to which IDcolor variable. This is what I have right now trying to paste every row into the variable m.

```
m <- ""
for(i in 1:nrow(g)){
  m[i] <- paste0(g[i,1],":",IDcolor1)
}
```

My desired output would be:

```
m
# [1] AA:50 25 197
# [2] AA:50 25 197
# [3] BB:131 255 58
# [4] BB:131 255 58
# [5] BB:131 255 58
# [6] CC:242 100 72
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful strategy for matching values to items is using `merge()`, by matching creating a data frame of your matching values. Then it's a really simple matter of combining into another variable using paste as you like.

```
g <- read.table(file = textConnection('ID Answers Questions
AA 1111111 222222222
AA 2222222 333333333
BB 3333333 444444444
BB 4444444 555555555
BB 5555555 666666666
CC 6666666 777777777'), header = TRUE)

for_merging <- data.frame(
ID=c("AA","BB","CC"),
response = c("50 25 197","131 255 58","242 100 72"))

> merge(g, for_merging)
  ID Answers Questions   response
1 AA 1111111 222222222  50 25 197
2 AA 2222222 333333333  50 25 197
3 BB 3333333 444444444 131 255 58
4 BB 4444444 555555555 131 255 58
5 BB 5555555 666666666 131 255 58
6 CC 6666666 777777777 242 100 72
```

Comment: Hi @Brandon Bertelsen, thanks for the answer. What if the ID column is not the first column in the table. In my actual data, the ID column is in the 3rd column, and therefore this method is not working

Comment: `?merge` looks up the name of the field and matches. Is the `ID` column you data actually named "ID", if not - change the name in the `for_merging` to match. Pay particular attention to the `by` argument in the merge docs. This should help.